# MySQL - ENUM - Good Idea for ISO 3166-1 Country Codes?

Tags: php, mysql, database, enums

I have a MySQL database table for tagging items in the database with 2-digit (ISO 3166-1) country codes (e.g. United States = US).

I am thinking of using an ENUM for the country codes tag column since country codes don't change that much and there's about ~200 or so of them.  Plus, this table could end up with a lot of rows so I figure using an ENUM will help it operate efficiently.

I've heard of people using ENUM with country codes in other situations on SO, but I am not sure if it is reasonable to do so when using MySQL.

What do you think -- is using an ENUM for 2-digit country codes in MySQL a good idea in my case?  Or will I regret this decision?

I'm using MySQL 5.6 and PHP 5.5.

Comment: I would prefer use separate table to store country codes. so in future you can add there  different column if needed like country name, or translation for different language, or the capital, or time zone or anything else. But the main goal is to keep it simple. There are just few situations when you really need all countries, usually we operate with some of them  1-2 for small companies, up to 20 for really big, but 100 countries - I am not sure what is your application for probably you really need it.

Comment: For my project, the idea is that items like 'articles' should almost always have at least one country tag that should be associatated with the article.  Some articles may have more than one country associated with them.  If there are many articles, then eventually this table will have a very large number of rows.  Other items in DB could also potentially be tagged too.

Comment: CHAR(2) will be fine. Handle data validation in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ENUM datatypes are typically used for very simple and non-changing values like custom boolean values (T/F, 0/1, Heads/Tails) or a very small subset of values that will not change like multiple choice answers (A, b, C, D, E).

If the values will change at all, I would not recommend an ENUM datatype (which is the case in our volatile world of changing borders).  It requires that you update the your table schema when you need to add or worse - delete a value from the ENUM value list.  ENUM datatypes are perfect for those fields where you need to be sure it is only one of a values in the defined field, and need error checking when a value outside the list is attempted.

I would recommend depending on how you are representing the country code, a very simple variable two character field (A2 ISO or A3 UN), a small integer (NUM UN).

Use a separate look up table (join in queries) to perform code expansion and other related country data (currency rates, residing continent, etc..)

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I suppose having to update the ENUM every time country codes change could be too obnoxious to justify using an ENUM, even if it takes less space to store.  I'll guess I'll go with a CHAR(2).

Comment: CHAR(2) works for A2 ISO, make sure you have no plans for A3 UN specifications for Country Codes.  http://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/ctycodes.htm